# How to set ANDROID_HOME environment variable in Termux on MEmu player?

Tags: python, environment-variables, appium

I am building a Appium script in Pydroid on MEmu player. So I installed Appium on Termux and run appium server. But when I run the script, I see this error.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vYaBp.png)
MEmu player is running on Windows 10 and I already installed Android SDK on this windows OS. The path is C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
I am using Termux for command prompt on MEmu player. How to set this environment variable?

I installed uiautomator2 and chromium driver for appium server.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors